# Adding an Email Confirmation to the Registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

So I've been trying to add "Confirm Email" field to my registration page.

I'm using these two pages as references:
http://magentopaper.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-add-confirmation-email-field-in.html
http://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/adding-confirm-e-mail-address-field-to-magento-frontend-forms.html

However for some reason, I can't get it to show up.

I've added this to `customer.xml`

```
<action method="addJs"><script>email/validation.js</script></action>
```

This to `validation.js`

```
['validate-cemail', 'Please make sure your emails match.', function(v) {
  var conf = $$('.validate-cemail')[0];
  var pass = false;
     if ($('email')) {
     pass = $('email');
 }
  var emailElements = $$('.validate-email');
  for (var i = 0; i < emailElements.size(); i++) {
  var emailElement = emailElements[i];
     if (emailElement.up('form').id == conf.up('form').id) {
     pass = emailElement;
 }
 }
    if ($$('.validate-admin-email').size()) {
    pass = $$('.validate-admin-email')[0];
 }
    return (pass.value == conf.value);
}],
```

And this to `register.phtml`

```
<label for="confirm_email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo$this >_('Confirm Email Address') ?></label><div class="input-box"><input type="text" name="confirm_email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Email') ?>" id="confirm_email" class="input-text required-entry validate-cemail" /></div>
```

Comment: Which register.phtml are you talking about ? The base theme includes a layout file called **persistent.xml** in which different templates are replaced by those in the template folder **persistent**. In the second link they are giving, they are speaking about the good template file, but in the first one, the "wrong". I guess it is something that wasn't existing at the time it was written.

Comment: I am indeed using the register.phtml inside the persistent folder. However, it isn't the exact one they provided in the link, since the one they provided contains no register.phtml.
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form is where the one I edited came from, since /app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml doesn't exist.